# jQuery login $.post

Tags: jquery, forms, authentication

I've been into jQuery lately, it's my first time using it, but I've made MAJOR improvements on my website with it. (fadeIn pages, switches, etc.)

So basically, I want to make a login form with it, but I've no idea how to use $.post even after having research on it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="username">
 <input type="password" id="password">
 <input type="submit" id="log" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Yea, that's where I am right now, and I'd like a fancy fade animation for logging. [or atleast no page load]

EDIT: looks like so right now, it's outputing 'failed.' even if I enter the right combo

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#loginform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.post('login.php', function(data) {
            $('body').hide();
        $('body').html(data).show('fast');
    });
});
});
</script>
 </head>
<body>
  <div id="all">
 <form action="" method="post" id="loginform">
  <input type="text" id="username"><br>
  <input type="password" id="password"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="log" value="Log in">
</form>
</div>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
 $un = $_POST['username'];
 $pw = $_POST['password'];
 if($un == "huwil" and $pw == "test") {
  echo "logged.";
 } else {
   echo "failed.";
 }
?>
```

Comment: you'd like to render the page after user logs in without refreshing the browser?

Comment: Exactly. If that's possible anyways. :P

Comment: Ajax is great for loading *small* or partial changes in the document. Usually the structure of an unauthenticated vs authenticated page differs so much that there's no point in using ajax (you'd just be sending the whole new page back). Of course, you can still submit the form via ajax to check if the login details are valid, and redirect after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a page after you login without having to refresh is actually possible, but I'm not sure if there's implication with cookies etc

`$.post` can be called in several ways, in your case, you need:

```
$.post(url, parameters_to_send_to_server, callback_function)
```

so:

```
$.post('login.php', $('#formId').serialize(), function(html) {
    $('body').hide();
    $('body').html(html).show('fast');
});
```

`$('#formId').serialize()` takes all data from the `form` with id `#formId`, packs it in a string, and sends to the server, so in your php you can access it as `$_POST['input_name']`, the `callback_function` runs whenever the AJAX request is completed.

Comment: Wrong result I guess? Not functioning.

Comment: @SevenofNine did you add id to your form? I can't post a fully functioning code without having access to your full code :s, this is something to get you started

Comment: I did. It's #loginform, but getting 'failed.' continously. :c

Comment: so did you change the code above to `$('#loginForm').serialize()` ? and `failed` is coming from your server?

Comment: indeed. still trying things tho

Comment: did you give `name` to your `<input>`s? `<input name="username" ...>` etc?

Comment: OH DAMN! that's what I've forgotten xD

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formIdorName").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.post('url', function(data) { // where `url` is the php page that handles your logic
     $('.result').html(data);// `data` is returned from server
   });
});



<form action="/" id="formIdorName">
 <input type="text" name="login" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<div id='result' />
```

Comment: So the 'url' is a php page which handles the 'data' and sends back the result if the user is logged in or not? I need a bit more explanation than that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how it doesn't work even with the right combo: I think you need a name attribute for POST: `<input type="password" id="password" name="password">`.

Just an extra little thing you might consider: you could have the login on the same page.

```
<?php if($_POST) { //if there's incoming POST data
 $un = $_POST['username'];
 $pw = $_POST['password'];
 if($un == "huwil" and $pw == "test") {
  echo "logged.";
 } else {
   echo "failed. <a href='/login.php'>retry</a>.";
 }
} else { //or if there's not
?>
<!--login form-->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: that's what I was aiming for and it's already done, but thanks anyways :)